# JavaScript to find which button is pressed among multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have multiple TextBoxes and multiple buttons on the page. If I hit Enter key while I'm in one TextBox the corresponding Button click event should be executed.

I have written the code like below, but It is not working. Can anybody please explain me how...

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button4_Click" />
</div>
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class JavaScriptEnterKey : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Attributes.Add("OnKeyDown", "HitButton('" + Button1.ClientID + "');");
        TextBox2.Attributes.Add("OnKeyDown", "HitButton('" + Button2.ClientID + "');");
        TextBox3.Attributes.Add("OnKeyDown", "HitButton('" + Button3.ClientID + "');");
        TextBox4.Attributes.Add("OnKeyDown", "HitButton('" + Button4.ClientID + "');");
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Button1 is clicked");
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Button2 is clicked");
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Button3 is clicked");
    }

    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Button4 is clicked");
    }

}


**JavaScript**
function HitButton(Button) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById(Button).click();
}
```

Comment: Do you need access to the other text boxes from the enter key press which 'belongs' to another? If not, you can probably achieve this type of behaviour by making multiple forms on the page.

Comment: I am having GridView with the facility to insert Record. That time, I cannot use your technique, right? :) I want JavaScript specific solution.

Comment: You can't have multiple forms in webforms. textbox control needs to be in a form control & only 1 form control is allowed

Answer (score 0):

Try using the keypress event rather than keycode. That seemed to work in my code.